# Enable the border for the panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have created a panel for my WordPress site.

I want to change the color of the border whenever my panel is opened to make it look nicer.

For this, I have used the following code, but it did not help:

```
.MyPanel ul:active {
    border: 2px solid #ff000059 !important;
}
```

or

```
.MyPanel ul:focus-visible {
    border: 2px solid #ff000059 !important;
}
```

By clicking on the panel and opening it, the border will appear only when you click and then it will be hidden. And also it shows and hides border panel content by clicking which I don't want.

The full code of the professional panel for WordPress:

```js
  $('.body_panel').find('li').click(function () {
            if ($(this).parent().find("ul").eq(0).is(':visible')) {

                $(this).children('.icon-title-left_panel').show();
                $(this).children('.icon-title-down_panel').hide();
            } else {
                $(this).children('.icon-title-left_panel').hide();
                $(this).children('.icon-title-down_panel').show();
            }
        });

        $('.MyPanel').find('li').click(function (evt) {
            evt.stopPropagation();
            $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
        });
```

```css
.MyPanel {
    max-width: 1200px;
    width: 85%;
    display: block;
    margin: 2rem auto 1rem;
    padding: 6px;
    text-align: right;
    direction: ltr;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.MyPanel ul {
    border: 2px solid #f3f3f359;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px #000, inset 0 0 200px #f3f3f375;
    padding: 20px 25px 55px;
    list-style: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.MyPanel ul:active {
    border: 2px solid #ff000059 !important;
}

.MyPanel ul:focus-visible {
    border: 2px solid #ff000059 !important;
}

.MyPanel ul ul li {
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.MyPanel ul li {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'byekan';
    font-size: 25px;
}

.MyPanel ul li h3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: -25px;
    right: 0;
    width: 92%;
    padding: 0 0 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    direction: rtl;
}

.MyPanel ul li h3:hover {
    color: #5000ff;
    text-shadow: 0 0 2px #e63131, 0 0 4px #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.MyPanel ul.box-contect_panel li.contect_panel hr.contect_panel-hr-start,
.MyPanel ul.box-contect_panel li.contect_panel hr.contect_panel-hr-end {
    width: 90%;
    border-top: 5px solid #0fd2ff;
    margin: 20px auto 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    list-style: none;
}

.MyPanel ul.box-contect_panel li.contect_panel hr.contect_panel-hr-end {
    margin: 50px auto 0;
}

.MyPanel ul.box-contect_panel li.contect_panel h4 {
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: justify;
    font-family: 'samim';
    font-size: 20px;
    direction: rtl;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 40px auto 0;
}

.MyPanel ul li .icon-title-left_panel,
.MyPanel ul li .icon-title-down_panel {
    position: absolute;
    top: -40px;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: #80c2fe;
}

.MyPanel ul li .icon-title-left_panel:hover,
.MyPanel ul li .icon-title-down_panel {
    color: #0086ff;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.MyPanel ul li .icon-title-down_panel {
    display: none;
    color: #ff8484;
}

.MyPanel ul li .icon-title-down_panel:hover {
    color: #f00;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.MyPanel ul li ul {
    display: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
    margin: 0 0 -60px;
}

.MyPanel ul li ul li {
    cursor: context-menu;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />




<div class="MyPanel">

        <ul class="body_panel">
            <li class="title_panel">
                <p class="bi bi-arrow-left-square-fill icon-title-left_panel">&shy;</p>
                <p class="bi bi-arrow-down-square-fill icon-title-down_panel">&shy;</p>

                <h3>title</h3>

                <ul class="box-contect_panel">
                    <li class="contect_panel">

                        <hr class="contect_panel-hr-start">

                        <h4>
                           Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis veniam voluptas doloremque saepe sapiente! Dolorum
    fugiat excepturi velit culpa ab.
                        </h4>

                        <hr class="contect_panel-hr-end">

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>


<div class="MyPanel">

        <ul class="body_panel">
            <li class="title_panel">
                <p class="bi bi-arrow-left-square-fill icon-title-left_panel">&shy;</p>
                <p class="bi bi-arrow-down-square-fill icon-title-down_panel">&shy;</p>

                <h3>title</h3>

                <ul class="box-contect_panel">
                    <li class="contect_panel">

                        <hr class="contect_panel-hr-start">

                        <h4>
                           Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis veniam voluptas doloremque saepe sapiente! Dolorum
    fugiat excepturi velit culpa ab.
                        </h4>

                        <hr class="contect_panel-hr-end">

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common practice is to add a 'active' class when the element is active and remove it when it's not then just style the active class .

```js
$('.body_panel').find('li.title_panel').click(function () { // added li class
            if ($(this).parent().find("ul").eq(0).is(':visible')) {
                $(this).parent().removeClass('active'); // Select ul relatively and remove class
                $(this).children('.icon-title-left_panel').show();
                $(this).children('.icon-title-down_panel').hide();
            } else {
                $(this).parent().addClass('active'); // Select ul relatively and add class
                $(this).children('.icon-title-left_panel').hide();
                $(this).children('.icon-title-down_panel').show();
            }
        });

        $('.MyPanel').find('li').click(function (evt) {
            evt.stopPropagation();
            $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
        });
```

```css
.MyPanel {
    max-width: 1200px;
    width: 85%;
    display: block;
    margin: 2rem auto 1rem;
    padding: 6px;
    text-align: right;
    direction: ltr;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.MyPanel ul {
    border: 2px solid #f3f3f359;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px #000, inset 0 0 200px #f3f3f375;
    padding: 20px 25px 55px;
    list-style: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.MyPanel ul.active {
    border: 2px solid #ff000059 !important;
}

.MyPanel ul ul li {
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.MyPanel ul li {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'byekan';
    font-size: 25px;
}

.MyPanel ul li h3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: -25px;
    right: 0;
    width: 92%;
    padding: 0 0 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    direction: rtl;
}

.MyPanel ul li h3:hover {
    color: #5000ff;
    text-shadow: 0 0 2px #e63131, 0 0 4px #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.MyPanel ul.box-contect_panel li.contect_panel hr.contect_panel-hr-start,
.MyPanel ul.box-contect_panel li.contect_panel hr.contect_panel-hr-end {
    width: 90%;
    border-top: 5px solid #0fd2ff;
    margin: 20px auto 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    list-style: none;
}

.MyPanel ul.box-contect_panel li.contect_panel hr.contect_panel-hr-end {
    margin: 50px auto 0;
}

.MyPanel ul.box-contect_panel li.contect_panel h4 {
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: justify;
    font-family: 'samim';
    font-size: 20px;
    direction: rtl;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 40px auto 0;
}

.MyPanel ul li .icon-title-left_panel,
.MyPanel ul li .icon-title-down_panel {
    position: absolute;
    top: -40px;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: #80c2fe;
}

.MyPanel ul li .icon-title-left_panel:hover,
.MyPanel ul li .icon-title-down_panel {
    color: #0086ff;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.MyPanel ul li .icon-title-down_panel {
    display: none;
    color: #ff8484;
}

.MyPanel ul li .icon-title-down_panel:hover {
    color: #f00;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.MyPanel ul li ul {
    display: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
    margin: 0 0 -60px;
}

.MyPanel ul li ul li {
    cursor: context-menu;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />




<div class="MyPanel">

        <ul class="body_panel">
            <li class="title_panel">
                <p class="bi bi-arrow-left-square-fill icon-title-left_panel">&shy;</p>
                <p class="bi bi-arrow-down-square-fill icon-title-down_panel">&shy;</p>

                <h3>title</h3>

                <ul class="box-contect_panel">
                    <li class="contect_panel">

                        <hr class="contect_panel-hr-start">

                        <h4>
                           Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis veniam voluptas doloremque saepe sapiente! Dolorum
    fugiat excepturi velit culpa ab.
                        </h4>

                        <hr class="contect_panel-hr-end">

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="body_panel">
            <li class="title_panel">
                <p class="bi bi-arrow-left-square-fill icon-title-left_panel">&shy;</p>
                <p class="bi bi-arrow-down-square-fill icon-title-down_panel">&shy;</p>

                <h3>title</h3>

                <ul class="box-contect_panel">
                    <li class="contect_panel">

                        <hr class="contect_panel-hr-start">

                        <h4>
                           Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis veniam voluptas doloremque saepe sapiente! Dolorum
    fugiat excepturi velit culpa ab.
                        </h4>

                        <hr class="contect_panel-hr-end">

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
```

Comment: Your solution is completely correct, but if there are two or more panels on the page, clicking on one of them will turn all the borders red. But I want only the clicked panel to get the red border.

Comment: I edited my question and added another panel.

Comment: @Developer Hay, in that case just change the selector accordingly. I've adjusted my answer take a look .

Comment: Hello. Clicking on the second ul where the content is located adds another border which makes the panel look very ugly. Is there a way to not add the margin to the second ul?

Comment: @Developer again just adjust the selector . look again at the updated code . first row of jquery i've updated the click selector .

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to solve my problem. Your solution is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is only you need to do

```
$(".body_panel")
                .find("li")
                .click(function () {
                    if ($(this).parent().find("ul").eq(0).is(":visible")) {
                        $(".body_panel").removeClass("active"); // Remove the class when closed 
                        $(this).children(".icon-title-left_panel").show();
                        $(this).children(".icon-title-down_panel").hide();
                    } else {
                        $(".body_panel").addClass("active"); // Add the class when active
                        $(this).children(".icon-title-left_panel").hide();
                        $(this).children(".icon-title-down_panel").show();
                    }
                });
    
            $(".MyPanel")
                .find("li")
                .click(function (evt) {
                    evt.stopPropagation();
                    $(this).children("ul").slideToggle();
                });
```